# How to repeat a sequence of number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel against which I want to create a column which contains the repeated sequence from the first column

what I have :

[image: Column A]

What I need against it:

[image: Column B]

Comment: would you like to see a solution in power query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step solution using **Power Query**:

Please note you need to have **Excel 2010 or later version** to be able to use Power Query. My version is **Excel 2016**.

I did not use any advanced coding but just a few **built-in functions** of the Power Query Editor in combination of **Text.Repeat** formula.

[image: Solution]

Here is the full code behind the scene just for reference only.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", "Column1 - Copy"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Column1", "Number"}, {"Column1 - Copy", "Text"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Text", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Custom", each Text.Repeat([Text],[Number])),
    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {{"Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByRepeatedLengths(1), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Custom"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Position",{{"Custom", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Custom"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing this:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,B1)=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$B$1:B1)))-1),INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$B$1:B1)))),INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SUMPRODUCT(1/(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$B$1:B1)))-1))
```

It's a rather long formula and can be significantly shorter, but I got a  feeling your sample data does not represent your real data, so this would work also for other number than constantly +1. For example:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I thought of doing with a cumulative sum, but it requires either a helper column or a subtotal/offset combination.

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, you can do it by looking up the row of the output column in the cumulative sums of the input column. I like the *idea* of getting the output directly from the row number, but I can't see a neat way of implementing it

(1) Helper column

Put the cumulative totals in column B:

```
=SUM(A1:A$1)-A1
```

Then just do a lookup in the output column:

```
=IF(ROW()>SUM(A$1:A$5),"",INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(ROW()-1,B$1:B$5)))
```

(2) Subtotal/offset combo:

```
=IF(ROW()>SUM(A$1:A$5),"",INDEX(A$1:A$5,MATCH(ROW()-1,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($A$1,0,0,ROW(A$1:A$5)))-A$1:A$5)))
```

This has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]